# Different durations for different transforms?

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions

I've set a transition and a transform for an element. I'd like to have different durations on each of my transformations (scale, perspective, rotate). Any way to achieve that?

Transition:

```
transition:-webkit-transform 1s linear;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear; /** Chrome & Safari **/
```

Transform:

```
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(50px, 114.82978723404256px, 0px) perspective(2000px) rotateX(40deg) scale(0.23297872340425532);
```

Comment: AFAIK, your only posibilities are 1) animations with keyframes 2) severals elements, and 1 transition for each.

Comment: If they didn't all use `transform` you could do it, so if you could change the scale by using width/height/position, but vals is correct

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it like following code. I've used it in my website and it works perfect.

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
```

Hope it helps!

Thanks

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about multiple CSS `transform` properties. `opacity` is not a `transform` property.